# Get multisite count without php?

Tags: multisite, database, query, mysql

I'm writing a program in Python that outputs information about Wordpress installations and I'm adding some features to detect Multisite installations and their details. I would like it to print how many sub-installations(?) exist in one multisite, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I think the built-in Wordpress function equivalent to what I need would be:

```
return get_site_option( 'blog_count' );
```

But I need a way to do that without PHP and I can't figure out what query Wordpress is running for that. I figured it would be stored in wp_options but nada.

How I'm getting the count now (example):

```
$ mysql -e "show tables from $database" | grep -c comments
3
```

because I figure each installation is going to have its own comments table. Ideally I'm just looking for a plain number stored in the database somewhere that says how many installations exist.

I'm not a Wordpress person so sorry if I'm scrambling any lingo here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: WP CLI can do all these things,and in PHP, perhaps you can make use of that ( executing WP CLI commands from python is doable )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information about the multisite option `blog_count` is stored in the table [`wp_sitemeta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_sitemeta). Taking a look at the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3/src/wp-includes/option.php#L972) is in such cases beneficial, if not invaluable.

Comment: My pleasure! Don't forget accepting the answers that were useful to you. @Respheal